# Remove ModelAndView from Swagger 3.0 UI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a Spring Boot application that uses `springdoc-openapi-ui` to document REST endpoint. Also, there is some simple UI with Spring MVC. For some reason, in Swagger UI I see not only schemas for REST but also the schema for ModelAndView class. Is there a way to remove it from there?

I've tried already some options like limiting packages to scan with `springdoc.packagesToScan` or  `springdoc.model-and-view-allowed` but without any results?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide a Controller or Schema classes with @Hidden annotation, like this:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Hidden;    

@RestController
@Hidden
public class ItemController
```

@Hidden annotation is part of springdoc-openapi-ui library.

Comment: Not sure why but that's also not working. BTW I don't see the endpoints of MVC controller only ModelAndView in the schema.